# get relation data from one table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table, let's called it `data_employee`. It contains:

```
(employee_name, username, department, division, group, job)
```

and the data is:

```
(john_doe, john.doe, **it_sec**, null, it, **network_adm**)
(smith_jaeger, smith.jaeger, **it_sec**, null, it, **Department_Head**)
```

I want to query username's superior, which is:

```
if username has department,
then filter their department (e.x: it_sec) and the job department_head
if username has not department,
then filter their division like above and so on deligate until group head
```

I've tried subquery but sometimes they return multiple data, because I have sub `group head`

and the data also written `group head`

so, for an example: the result is:

> when I want to find john_doe's department head, the result is
>   smith_jaeger

Comment: Please make it easy for us and show us your expected result.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this query:

```
select de1.employee_name, de2.employee_name
from data_employee de1
join data_employee de2
on ((de1.department = de2.department) and (de1.job <> 'Department_Head') and (de2.job = 'Department_Head')) or
((de1.department is null) and (de1.division = de2.division) and (de2.job <> 'Department_Head'))
```

The first criteria is before the `or`, the second criteria is after the `or`. In the first criteria it's important to specify that an employee is department head and the other is not to avoid having results saying that the department head is his/her own boss. With the second criteria we did not exclude duplicates, because if there could be separate departments with the same division (which should not be the case, but we cannot exclude inconsistency, especially if these are textual data), then the multiple bosses of the separate departments of the same division will appear in the results. Also, if there are multiple department heads, that's a problem as well.

Comment: Sorry for unclear question because I can't post my real schema on here, but it's closer to my real schema. once again, thank you